# QuerySet в Django, как преобразовать в объект модели типа <Model : key>

Tags: python, django

Новичок в Django и вообще в программировании столкнулся с проблемой когда я получаю  id пользователя и в функции выполняю `user = User.objects.filter(pk = current_request.userId) и print(user)` такую команду в консоли мне выводит `<QuerySet [<User: polopolaw>]>`. 
Если же я запускаю похожий код в shell вывод будет просто `polopolaw`

Проблема в том что в шелле у меня получается подтянуть основную таблицу и сохранить объект в базу данных а в приложении выдает ошибку 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'

Ниже код приложения:

```
from shop.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        user = User.objects.filter(pk = current_request.userId)
        print(current_request.userId)
        print(user)
        user.profile.balance += int(float(cur_vtor_stat.convertPersent) * v)
        user.profile.count_recoin += int(float(cur_vtor_stat.convertPersent) * v)
        user.profile.count_request += 1
        user.save()
        current_request.save()
```

Ошибка AttributeError at /dispatcher/finish/35
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'

Что самое непонятное точно такой код, несколько упрощенный спокойно дает сохранить объект, `user = User.objects.filter(pk = current_request.userId)` после этой строчки user это объект `<user: polopolaw>`

Answer (score 2):

`filter()` всегда возвращает набор объектов - QuerySet, который может содержать несколько объектов User. Вы можете итерировать по нему как по списку. Он не имеет атрибута profile. Вам нужен именно объект User.

Вместо `filter()` можно использовать `get()`, который возвращает один объект.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk = current_request.userId)
```

Или вызвать методы `first()` или `last()` у QuerySet.

```
user = User.objects.filter(pk = current_request.userId).first()
```